# finding intersection of three growing circles

Tags: math, geometry

There are three points on a line which are center of three circles. Initial radius of each circle is defined and they have no overlaps in their initial state. Then all of them start growing and increasing their radius with similar and same speed/ratio (for example 1cm/sec for all of them).

How can I find intersection of these circles in time? I mean finding out when these three circles meet each other in two points?

[image: Initial state (measurements are not accurate)]

[image: final state where I want to find elapsed time]

Comment: How is this a computer programming question? If you add your own efforts at solving the problem this would be a better fit for the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, namely [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RoryDaulton, This is definitely a programming question. I am trying to find an algorithm to calculate elapsed time in C. So this must be a programming question. Just because it does not contain semicolons it doesn't mean it is not related to programming :)

Comment: In general, make it clear in your original question just how it is related to programming. Thanks for making it clear now for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's middle circle is always centered at 0, left one - at `-da`, right one - at `dc`. Every radius depends on time like this: `Ra(t) = ra + k * t`. So using formula (5) from [mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html), we can write equation for x-coordinate of intersections (check the signs thoroughly):

```
- (da^2 - (ra+k*t)^2 + (rb+k*t)^2)/da = (dc^2 - (rc+k*t)^2 + (rb+k*t)^2)/dc
```

and solve it for unknown `t`, then check whether this value gives real intersection.

Comment: Thank you @MBo , this method rocks